# Water mark posted to server when using DropdownList in UpdatePanel

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, webforms

If you place a text field with the jQuery.watermark plugin applied to it and a DropdownList that has AutoPostback set to true within an UpdatePanel the watermark is not cleared from the text field when the Dropdown list changed.

The water mark from the text field is posted to the server as the value of the text field which is not correct. If you do not use an UpdatePanel the watermark value is correctly cleared by the plugin's form submission code.

From what I can gather the problem is that the postback generated for the DropdownList is done entirely in JavaScript by-passing the form's submit event handlers which is how the plugin would clear the watermark value. The various [ASP.NET AJAX JavaScript events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb398976.aspx) are all fired after the body of the post has been built so I cannot use them to remove the watermark. Is there some other way of doing this?

This only applies to browsers that do not have native support for the placeholder attribute, most notably IE9 and below.

I have [raised this as a bug for the plugin here](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/issues/detail?id=82).

Code to reproduce this:

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />
    <div>
        Demonstration. 
        <br />
        <br />
        Note: This is only a problem for browsers that do not have have text field placeholder support. Most notabily Internet Explorer 9 and below.
        <ol>
            <li>The text field has a watermark 'wattery' applied to it</li>
            <li>The dropdown list is set to auto postback</li>
            <li>When you change the dropdown list the watermark is not removed and is posted to the server as the value of the text field</li>
            <li>When you click either the button or the link the watermark is removed as these actions trigger the 'beforeunload' event.</li>
        </ol>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt" />
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl" AutoPostBack="true" 
                    onselectedindexchanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="one" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="two" />
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:Button Text="Click me 1" runat="server" />
                <asp:LinkButton Text="Click me 2" runat="server" />
                <br />
                <br />

                Value from text field after postback = '<asp:Label Text="" runat="server" ID="lbl" />'
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.watermark.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $().ready(function () {
            $('#<%=txt.ClientID %>').watermark("wattery");
        });

    </script>
```

```
protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbl.Text = txt.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty old thread but had this issue recently. Here's something I came up with.

```
$('#<%=Button1.ClientID%>').click(function () { 
                if (typeof("Page_ClientValidate") === "function") {
                    if (Page_ClientValidate()) {
                        $.watermark.hideAll();
                    }
                    else {
                        $.watermark.showAll();
                    }
                }
                else { $.watermark.hideAll(); }
});
```

Note: Not 100% tested but something along that line should work.